# Order by date in sub-document and then by document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a simple "Event" mongo schema. Two sample documents are below :

### Event Document #1

```js
{
  "event_name": "Some nice event",
  "venues": [
    {
      "venue_name": "venue #1",
      "shows": [
        {
          "show_time": "2014-06-18T07:46:02.415Z",
          "capacity": 20
        },
        {
          "show_time": "2014-06-20T07:46:02.415Z",
          "capacity": 40
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "venue_name": "venue #2",
      "shows": [
        {
          "show_time": "2014-06-17T07:46:02.415Z",
          "capacity": 20
        },
        {
          "show_time": "2014-06-24T07:46:02.415Z",
          "capacity": 40
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Event Document #2

```js
{
  "event_name": "Another nice event",
  "venues": [
    {
      "venue_name": "venue #1",
      "shows": [
        {
          "show_time": "2014-06-19T07:46:02.415Z",
          "capacity": 20
        },
        {
          "show_time": "2014-06-16T07:46:02.415Z",
          "capacity": 40
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to query this collection of event documents and fetch the events with the closest shows, with respective to a particular time.

So for e.g., if I had to find events happening on or after *16 Jun*, I should get document #2 followed by document #1, with the venue sub-document order as [venue #2, venue #1].

On the other hand, if I wanted events happening on or after *18 Jun*, I should get document #1, with [venue #1, venue #2], followed by document #2.

Essentially, I need to be able to sort by the start_time of the nested sub-document. And this sorting should work on multiple venue sub-documents.

According to mongo's documentation, this doesn't seem to be supported, so is there a way of using aggregation to achieve this?

Or is there a way to rejig the schema to support such queries?

Or is mongoDB the wrong use-case for such scenarios altogether?

Comment: Is this just a JSON dump? I hope your actual "date" fields are real "date" Objects and not strings.

Comment: Yes, of course. Though I'm tempted to store them as Numbers corresponding to the UTC Timestamp.

Comment: I was really only just asking since it was not clear from how you posted your question. I believe you got an answer anyway, so should not your priority here be "thank-you"? "Yes, of course" really does not add any value here.

Comment: Was just posting the thank you, went through in order of comments! Apologies if that seemed ungenerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really good question. Hoping that your dates are real date but the lexical form should not really matter here. The following form should do it, as long as you take the dates into consideration:

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    // Match the "documents" that meet the condition
    { "$match": {
        "venues.shows.show_time": { "$gte": new Date("2014-06-16") }
    }},

    // Unwind the arrays
    { "$unwind": "$venues" },
    { "$unwind": "$venues.shows" },

    // Sort the entries just to float the nearest result
    { "$sort": { "venues.shows.show_time": 1 } },

    // Find the "earliest" for the venue while grouping
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "event_name": "$event_name",
            "venue_name": "$venues.venue_name"
        },
        "shows": {
            "$push": "$venues.shows"
        },
        "earliest": { 
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [
                     { "$gte": [ 
                         "$venues.shows.show_time",
                         new Date("2014-06-16")
                     ]},
                     "$venues.shows.show_time",
                     null
                 ]
             }
        }
    }},

    // Sort those because of the order you want
    { "$sort": { "earliest": 1 } },

    // Group back and with the "earliest" document
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "event_name": { "$first": "$_id.event_name" },
        "venues": {
           "$push": {
               "venue_name": "$_id.venue_name",
               "shows": "$shows"
           }
        },
        "earliest": { 
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [
                     { "$gte": [ 
                         "$earliest",
                         new Date("2014-06-16")
                     ]},
                     "$earliest",
                     null
                 ]
             }
        }
    }},

    // Sort by the earliest document
    { "$sort": { "earliest": 1 } },

    // Project the fields
    { "$project": {
        "event_name": 1,
        "venues": 1
    }}
])
```

So most of this looks reasonable straightforward if you have some experience with the aggregation framework. If not then there is some general explaining, plus there are some "funky" things happening as we evaluate further.

The first steps in aggregation are to [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) just like any normal query and then to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the arrays you want to process. The "unwind" statement effectively "de-normalizes" the documents contained in the array to be standard documents by themselves.

The next [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) ends up as a "prettying up" function as the "earliest" event in each "set" will be at the top as a result.

As there are "two" levels of arrays, you do the grouping in two stages via the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage.

The first [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) "groups" by "document", "event_name" and "venue". All of the shows are put back into their original array form, but at this time we extract the [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) value for the "show_time".

The value taken is not just the ordinary "minimal" value. Here we use the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to make sure that the value returned must be "greater than or equal to" the date that you were requesting in the query initially. This makes sure that any "earlier" values are not taken into consideration when "sorting".

The next thing to do is to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on that "earliest" date, to keep the entries for the "venues" in order. The following stages then do the same as above, but "grouping" back to the original documents this time, then finally "sorting" in the order of which "show_time" would be the "earliest".

The result from the dates shown as input would be your desired result for the 16th:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a95263a1923f45a6c2d3dd"),
    "event_name" : "Another nice event",
    "venues" : [
        {
            "venue_name" : "venue #1",
            "shows" : [
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-16T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 40
                },
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-19T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a952b5a1923f45a6c2d3de"),
    "event_name" : "Some nice event",
    "venues" : [
        {
            "venue_name" : "venue #2",
            "shows" : [
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-17T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 20
                },
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 40
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "venue_name" : "venue #1",
            "shows" : [
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-18T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 20
                },
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-20T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 40
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And by changing the input to the 18th you also get the desired result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a952b5a1923f45a6c2d3de"),
    "event_name" : "Some nice event",
    "venues" : [
        {
            "venue_name" : "venue #1",
            "shows" : [
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-18T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 20
                },
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-20T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 40
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "venue_name" : "venue #2",
            "shows" : [
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-17T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 20
                },
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 40
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a95263a1923f45a6c2d3dd"),
    "event_name" : "Another nice event",
    "venues" : [
        {
            "venue_name" : "venue #1",
            "shows" : [
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-16T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 40
                },
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-19T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also if you want to go further with this, just add an additional [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage, and that can filter out "events" that occur before the date that is requested in the query:

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "venues.shows.show_time": { "$gte": new Date("2014-06-18") }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$venues" },
    { "$unwind": "$venues.shows" },
    { "$match": {
        "venues.shows.show_time": { "$gte": new Date("2014-06-18") }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "venues.shows.show_time": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "event_name": "$event_name",
            "venue_name": "$venues.venue_name"
        },
        "shows": {
            "$push": "$venues.shows"
        },
        "earliest": { 
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [
                     { "$gte": [ 
                         "$venues.shows.show_time",
                         new Date("2014-06-18")
                     ]},
                     "$venues.shows.show_time",
                     null
                 ]
             }
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "earliest": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "event_name": { "$first": "$_id.event_name" },
        "venues": {
           "$push": {
               "venue_name": "$_id.venue_name",
               "shows": "$shows"
           }
        },
        "earliest": { 
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [
                     { "$gte": [ 
                         "$earliest",
                         new Date("2014-06-18")
                     ]},
                     "$earliest",
                     null
                 ]
             }
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "earliest": 1 } },
    { "$project": {
        "event_name": 1,
        "venues": 1
    }}
])
```

With the result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a952b5a1923f45a6c2d3de"),
    "event_name" : "Some nice event",
    "venues" : [
        {
            "venue_name" : "venue #1",
            "shows" : [
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-18T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 20
                },
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-20T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 40
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "venue_name" : "venue #2",
            "shows" : [
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 40
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a95263a1923f45a6c2d3dd"),
    "event_name" : "Another nice event",
    "venues" : [
        {
            "venue_name" : "venue #1",
            "shows" : [
                {
                    "show_time" : ISODate("2014-06-19T07:46:02.415Z"),
                    "capacity" : 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I tried to use the aggregation framework, but the `$sort` was where I was stuck. The `$cond` seems to do the trick, thanks for pointing that out! One last follow-up question - is there a severe performance penalty for using such the aggregation framework? Thanks again for this insightful answer!

Comment: @Neeharv The main "penalty" should generally be outweighed by the initial use of `$match`, where the intention is to "limit" the input that goes into the aggregation pipeline as documents. After that, using `$unwind` with "large" arrays is not going to be beneficial. See the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator and/or tour various Q&A style questions I have posted from [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn?tab=questions) as a better indicator of how to use that. MongoDB 2.6 or later of course.